# should web.xml contents should be in order?

Tags: java, spring, web.xml

my current web.xml file looks like this. and this is does not show any error.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:com/udemy/spring/config/security-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-
class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

but for example if i reshuffle the code order for eg. like this

```
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-
class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-
class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:com/udemy/spring/config/security-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

i am getting this error:-

```
The content of element type "web-app" must match "(icon?,display- name?,
description?,distributable?,context-param*,servlet*,servlet-
mapping*,session-config?,mime- mapping*,welcome-file-list?,error-
page*,taglib*,resource-ref*,security-constraint*,login-
config?,security- role*,env-entry*,ejb-ref*)".
```

can someone explain me what might be the reason?

Comment: Where is the web-app tag in your second example? And in which line you get These error?

Answer (score 1):

The order of `web.xml` elements is defined in the `DTD` file that you have specified in the first line to be used to validate the `web.xml`

> http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd

If you open this file, you will see the order as follows:

1. icon
2. display-name
3. description
4. ...  etc

As it is defined in this element:

```
<!ELEMENT web-app (icon?, display-name?, description?, distributable?,
context-param*, filter*, filter-mapping*, listener*, servlet*,
servlet-mapping*, session-config?, mime-mapping*, welcome-file-list?,
error-page*, taglib*, resource-env-ref*, resource-ref*, security-  constraint*,
login-config?, security-role*, env-entry*, ejb-ref*,  ejb-local-ref*)>
```

Comment: great answer! though this is different in servlet 3.1 dtd

Answer (score 0):

web.xml file validates by dtd or xml schema.

In this example by http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd

So  web.xml has strictly defined order of tags according to this dtd